# How to save websocket frames in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, logging, websocket, trace, developer-tools

I am logging websocket traffic using Chrome/Developer Tools. I have no problem to view the websocket frames in network "Frames" window, but I can not save all frames (content enc. as JSON) in an external (text) file.
I have already tried save as HAR and also simply used cntl A,C,V (first "page" copied only) but have so far not been very successful.

I am running Linux Mint 17.

Do you have hints how this can be done?

Answer (score 22):

From **Chrome 76** the **HAR** file now includes **WebSocket messages**.

**[WebSocket messages in HAR exports](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/05/devtools#websocket)**

The `_webSocketMessages` property begins with an underscore to indicate that it's a custom field.

```
...
"_webSocketMessages": [
  {
    "type": "send",
    "time": 1558730482.5071473,
    "opcode": 1,
    "data": "Hello, WebSockets!"
  },
  {
    "type": "receive",
    "time": 1558730482.5883863,
    "opcode": 1,
    "data": "Hello, WebSockets!"
  }
]
...
```

Answer (score 19):

**Update for Chrome 63, January 2018**

---

I managed to export them as JSON as this:

1. **detach** an active inspector (if necessary)
2. start an inspector on the inspector with ctrl-shift-j/cmd-opt-j
3. paste the following code into that inspector instance.

At this point, you can do whatever you want with the frames. I used the `console.save` utility from https://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/#console-save to save the frames as a JSON file (included in the snippet below).

```
// https://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/#console-save 
(function(console){
  console.save = function(data, filename){
    if(!data) {
      console.error('Console.save: No data')
      return;
    }

    if(!filename) filename = 'console.json'

    if(typeof data === "object"){
      data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
    }

    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
    e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
    a = document.createElement('a')

    a.download = filename
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    a.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    a.dispatchEvent(e)
  }
})(console)

// Frame/Socket message counter + filename
var iter = 0;

// This replaces the browser's `webSocketFrameReceived` code with the original code 
// and adds two lines, one to save the socket message and one to increment the counter.
SDK.NetworkDispatcher.prototype.webSocketFrameReceived = function (requestId, time, response) {
  var networkRequest = this._inflightRequestsById[requestId];
  if (!networkRequest) return;
  console.save(JSON.parse(response.payloadData), iter + ".json")
  iter++;
  networkRequest.addFrame(response, time, false);
  networkRequest.responseReceivedTime = time;
  this._updateNetworkRequest(networkRequest);
}
```

This will save all incoming socket frames to your default download location.

Comment: I get an SDK not defined when using your code. Any pointers on how to get that to work?

Comment: Resolved this. For those who face this later - once you have the new inspector-inspector defined, you need to type in the code into the new window, but all your other WS activity is going to be output/recorded in the original console/browser window.

Comment: If you just want to dump all the frames from an existing wss frame log, you can do something like this: ``console.save(BrowserSDK.networkLog.requests()[18]._frames, "frames.json")``

Comment: @richardw hi, I want to do exactly what you said but can't, what's your chrome version? Can you tell more how you do please.

Comment: @bertrandg I'm now using `Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and it looks like `BrowserSDK` is now just `SDK`. I just tested it again with the following code: `console.save(SDK.networkLog.requests()[27]._frames, "frames.json")`. Hope that helps.

Comment: ...and if you don't understand what "once you have the new inspector-inspector defined" means, do this:
1) Open a devtools window on the page performing the websockets traffic   
2) Open a new tab to `chrome://inspect/#other`   
3) You should see a chrome-devtools item there now   
4) Click "Inspect". A new devtools window will open. *That* is your inspector-inspector, that is, a devtools window that is inspecting the first devtools window.

Comment: See also (for step 1): [How do you inspect the web inspector in Chrome? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291138/how-do-you-inspect-the-web-inspector-in-chrome)

Answer (score 4):

> This is something that is not possible to put into HAR format at this
>   time because HAR specification does not have details on how to export
>   framed transfer formats like WebSockets

From here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/jUOLFqpu-2Y

Answer (score 0):

There is an open request for this feature

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=496006

please "star" it to raise the priority.