# open chrome devtool inspector-inspector in selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I wish to save (secure) WebSocket traffic from some web pages. I tried saving HAR using `chrome-devtool`. But apparently, [it doesn't save the WebSocket traffic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/jUOLFqpu-2Y). However, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953531/how-to-save-websocket-frames-in-chrome/44957049) which suggests I can log all requests if I can change the `SDK` and log all `SDK.networkLog.requests()`. Still, to run `SDK` code, I would need to open the `chrome inspector-inspector` from Selenium. I know I can open the dev-tool using selenium from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311191/how-to-open-chrome-developer-console-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java). Any suggestion on how to open the `inspector-inspector`? Or alternate way to log `WebSocket`? 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what your programming language?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [wshook](https://github.com/skepticfx/wshook) to intercept and modify WebSocket requests and message events. Using `executeScript()` or `execute_script()` inject the following script to the page.

```
(function() {
  window.sentMessage = [];
  window.receivedMessage = [];
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/skepticfx/wshook@0.1.1/wsHook.js';
  s.onload = function() {
    window.wsHook.before = function(data, url) {
      window.sentMessage.push(data);
      console.log("Sending message to " + url + " : " + data);
    }

    window.wsHook.after = function(messageEvent, url, wsObject) {
      window.receivedMessage.push(messageEvent.data);
      console.log("Received message from " + url + " : " + messageEvent.data);
      return messageEvent;
    }
  }
  document.body.appendChild(s)
})();
```

After code above executed later you can get the data array from variables `window.sentMessage` and  `window.receivedMessage`

Answer (score 1):

So you can use Chrome Remote Debugging protocol as solution.Starting Chrome 63 even if Selenium is controlling the browser, other clients can connect to chrome and debug it.you can start chrome with the `--remote-debugging-port` option. I have not personally worked on logging web-socket traffic but have worked on some chrome profiling and this should be able to help. Here are some resources for your review :
[Chrome dev protocol viewer](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/)
 check if this resource could help [chrome-remote-interface](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/)
also this [Selenium + Chrome Dev-tools makes a Perfect Browser Automation Recipe](https://medium.com/@sahajamit/selenium-chrome-dev-tools-makes-a-perfect-browser-automation-recipe-c35c7f6a2360)